# Is there a solution for this traversal problem?

Tags: graph-algorithm

Say we have a matrix `M x N`,given two randomly specified `exit` and `entrance`,

find a path(up,down,left,right) from `entrance` to `exit` that covers each node in the matrix only once?

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously not always solvable. Say you have this matrix, where A is entrance and B exit:

```
+---+---+
| A |   |
+---+---+
|   | B |
+---+---+
```

How do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is something like this:

Split your matrix in two such that `entrance` and `exit` are in different partitions. Then, for each valid pair of cells that form a "bridge" over the split, recursively find whether or not there are valid paths from `entrance` to the cell in its partition, and from that cell's pair to `exit`. If none of the pairs work, then we can't find a path (because if such a path existed, it has to cross that partition *eventually*).

Using a small example, suppose we had

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
|   |   |
+---+---+
```

and split it down in the middle to give

```
+---+     +---+
| A |     | B |
+---+     +---+
|   | <-> |   |
+---+     +---+
```

with <-> being the only valid "bridge." Naming the cells in that pair "C" and "D", we then have

```
+---+     +---+
| A |     | B |
+---+     +---+
| C | <-> | D |
+---+     +---+
```

where we now find paths from A to C and from D to B. Splicing those mini paths together, we get A to C to D to B.

In the example given by Emil, no matter which way you partition that matrix, you can't get a valid pair to test, so you can immediately conclude that there is no such path.